# How do i call External Code from Oct Files without Errors?

Tags: fortran, octave, wrapper, compiler-warnings, undefined-reference

I want to run a Fortran program within Octave. I found a document, that has an example that i followed step by step. Here is the [link](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Calling-External-Code-from-Oct_002dFiles.html). I compiled fortransub.f with the command `gfortran -c fortransub.f` and fortrandemo.cc with the command `mkoctfile -c fortrandemo.cc`. Now i have two header files. In the document it says :

> Both the Fortran and C++ files need to be compiled in order for the example to work.

For me it is really a vague statement. Now to my problem. I don't know if i have to create an octfile. When i try to create one with the command `mkoctfile fortrandemo.cc` i get the following error:

```
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\goebl\AppData\Local\Temp/oct-A409yh.o: in function `Ffortrandemo(octav
e_value_list const&, int)':
C:\Users\goebl\Desktop\Test_1/fortrandemo.cc:23: undefined reference to `fortransub_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

When i try to run the command that is the next step in the document, i get the following error:

```
mkoctfile fortrandemo.cc fortransub.f
gfortran: fatal error: cannot specify '-o' with '-c', '-S' or '-E' with multiple files
compilation terminated.
```

What did i miss or did wrong? Can someone help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Command `mkoctfile fortrandemo.cc fortransub.f` does not issue any errror for me on OpenSuSE Linux and Octave 5.2.0. What OS and Octave versions do you use?

Comment: I have Windows 10 and i have the Octave 5.2.0 version!